# Cognos Mobile constant 401

Tags: ipad, vpn, cognos-bi

Could anyone point me in the right direction of what may be causing me to see multiple requests on my Cognos BI server.

When I review my IIS logs I see three attempts for each request.  The first two get a 401 response, and then eventually the third passes credentials through and gets a 200.

```
username method status uri-stem
         POST   401    /ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll/mobileService/content.json
         POST   401    /ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll/mobileService/content.json
ckemp    POST   200    /ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognosisapi.dll/mobileService/content.json
```

All of the entries above have the same User Agent, so I know they're coming from the iPad: IBM+Cognos+Mobile/10.2.1.4.3+(iPad;+iPhone+OS/7.1.2;+en-GB/en_GB)

My server is setup to use SSO and has only Windows Authentication enabled.  My iPad connects to the corporate network through an Aventail VPN connection.

The end result of this is that Cognos Mobile is EXCEEDINGLY slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is being caused by our Aventail VPN tunnelling software.